# How to add new key value pair in response of groupBy in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, group-by

I have a order table where it contains `id,order_id,user_id,etc`

I applied `groupBy()` over order Eloquent like below:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereUserId($userId)->groupBy('order_id')->get();
```

So, here I am getting response like:

```
Collection {#547 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "d0b942a572941b90f385" => Collection {#535 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => Order {#561 ▶}
        1 => Order {#562 ▶}
        2 => Order {#563 ▶}
        3 => Order {#564 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am applying foreach loop over here so that I can add new kew value pair to particular  above 4 array but Its now adding this new key value pair. I done the code like below:

```
foreach($orders as $order){

   $order['ee']='test';
 }
```

I am not getting where I am getting it wrong, because I check it line by line in foreach loop then it add it properly but while I check outside of loop, its now showing me this new key value pair

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the elements you itereate, better use map:

```
$orders = $orders->map(function($order) {
   $order['ee'] = 'test';
   return $order;
});
```